# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drush\Commands\DrushCommands' not found

Tags: 8, drush, migrations

I am trying to migrate data using csv source to Drupal 8 installation using Drush and Drupal Migrate Tools. I am able to execute all the drush commands including the one to check the migration status (drush ms). But while I execute Migrate Import command (drush migrate-import {migrate-id}), I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drush\Commands\DrushCommands' not found in {SiteName}/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php on line 23
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                         [error]
Error: Class 'Drush\Commands\DrushCommands' not found in
{SiteName}/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php, line 23
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Drupal Version: 8.9.3
Drush Version: 8.1.17
Migrate Tools: 8.x-4.5

Comment: Migrate Tools doesn't really support Drush 8. This is from the module page: _Drush 8 support in 4.x is best effort at this point_. Upgrading to Drush 9 would probably be the best solution here. Otherwise check this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools/issues/3099611), the patch in #24 might help

Comment: @Clive Updating the drush worked. Thanks.